terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::erase: __pos (which is 18446744073709551615)
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a,b; cin >> a;
    b="WUB";
    int n;
    while(a.find(b)==0){
        a.erase(0,3);
    }
    while(a.find(b)>0){
        n=a.find(b);
        a.replace(n,3," ");
    }
    n=a.size();

    while(a[--n]==' '){
        a.erase(n,1);
    }
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}

Basically, I have to remove WUB from the input string, and if it's between words then switch it with space, but I am getting the error mentioned in the title. By commenting out different blocks one by one, I found out that the error is in the 2nd while loop.
sample input :
WUBWUBABCWUB WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB
Can you tell what the problem is and how to resolve it?
This is my first query on StackOverflow, so sorry if I didn't provide some important info that I should have.

From here: while(a.find(b)>0), do you know what value is returned when a substring is not found?

Lookup std::string::npos

Minor point (very minor): formally, output to a stream must end with a newline character. So std::cout << a << '\n';. In the real world this doesn't matter; your program will work just fine (except that some folks are surprised to see their command prompt on the end of their output line). This requirement is a leftover from the days of record-oriented I/O on ancient mainframes, which required major gymnastics to pack lines of text into a series of fixed-size records.

Side note: Please read Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? and What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. You can also upvote any helpful answer (voting and accepting is separate). See here: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

std::string::find() returns an unsigned integer type.  If the requested substring is not found, it returns std::string::npos:

static const size_type npos = -1;
This is a special value equal to the maximum value representable by the type size_type. The exact meaning depends on context, but it is generally used either as end of string indicator by the functions that expect a string index or as the error indicator by the functions that return a string index.
Note
Although the definition uses -1, size_type is an unsigned integer type, and the value of npos is the largest positive value it can hold, due to signed-to-unsigned implicit conversion. This is a portable way to specify the largest value of any unsigned type.

Your 1st while loop handles npos correctly, but only because the value of npos is not 0.

On a side note: you don't need to search the whole string just to see if it begins with the substring. You can use std::string::compare() for that instead (or std::string::starts_with() in C++20 and later).

Your 2nd while loop fails to handle npos at all, as the value of npos is greater than 0, so you end up passing npos to std::string::replace() when no more WUBs are found, which then fails with the std::out_of_range exception.

On a side note: calling a.find() twice per loop iteration is redundant. Also, find() lets you specify the index where to begin searching from. Since you already know the index where you replace characters, you can have the next find() call start from that position instead of going all the way back to the beginning of the string every time.

You also have another potential out-of-bounds access, in your 3rd while loop.  If n is 0 because a is blank before the loop, or becomes blank during the loop, then you will decrement n below 0, which will wrap to a very large positive value when passed to std::string::operator[], causing undefined behavior (as operator[] doesn't perform any bounds checking. You can use std::string::at() instead if you want that).

On a side note: you can use std::string::back() to access the last character in the string. But using an erase() loop is not the most efficient way to trim whitespace from the end of a string, see How to trim a std::string? for alternatives.

With that said, try this instead:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a, b;
    cin >> a;
    b = "WUB";

    while (a.compare(0, b.size(), b) == 0) {
        a.erase(0, b.size());
    }

    string::size_type n = 0;
    while ((n = a.find(b, n)) != string::npos) {
        a.replace(n, b.size(), " ");
        ++n;
    }

    while ((!a.empty()) && (a.back() == ' ')) {
        a.erase(a.size()-1, 1);
    }

    cout << a;
    return 0;
}


the previous answer cleared my doubt but thanks for the advice on optimization because even after correction i am getting WA in test 4 for some reason i cant figure out
will implement it right away. thx and have a nice day
edit: abt the third while loop...it will work nonethless cuz there is at least one non-WUB  word in there

std::string::find does not return an int, but rather a std::string::size_type, which is an unsigned type (size_t is commonly used for it, but it's not guaranteed).
Moreover, when it fails to find the substring, it returns a special value of npos. Since it is unsigned, this value cannot be below 0.
From the documentation link above:

Return value
Position of the first character of the found substring or npos if no
such substring is found.

Therefore:

You need to change n to be a std::string::size_type:
std::string::size_type n;


You need to change:
while (a.find(b) > 0) {  // BTW: didn't you mean `>=` here ?

To:
while (a.find(b) != std::string::npos) {



Then the output for the input you mentioned will be:
ABC   WE ARE  THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND

Live demo
Side notes:
(1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?
(2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?

Technically, string::find() returns a string::size_type, which is usually but not guaranteed to be size_t. It can be any unsigned type the implementation wants.

@RemyLebeau thanks, corrected. Also +1 for your answer as it completes mine.
